# How to attach both Audio file and an image to E-Mail?

Tags: android, android-intent

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to attach audio file from SD card to E-Mail in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13724491/how-to-attach-audio-file-from-sd-card-to-e-mail-in-android)

I want to attach Audio file which is coming from SD Card and an Image Coming from Resource/drawable folder.And I want to delete audio file from SD card After Mail sent Successfully to Receiver.Please someone help me for my this Issue.Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

try this for audio:

```
 private File file;
 file = new File("audio file name/ path");
    File filelocation = file ;
    Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sharingIntent.setType("audio/mp4");
    sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com" );
    sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file://"+filelocation.getAbsolutePath()));
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Send email"));
```

try this for image:

```
  private File file;
  file = new File("your image path");
    File filelocation = file ;
    Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sharingIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
    sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, "XXXXXXXXX@gmail.com" );
    sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file://"+filelocation.getAbsolutePath()));
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Send email"));
```

Comment: but how to attach both image from drawable and an Audio file to email?

Comment: u have to add both image and audio file in same mail from drawable??

Comment: how to attach audio file from assets folder to email?

Comment: u have to send audio file from sdcard is it right??

Comment: yes.is it possible to attach audio file from Assets folder?i want to send audio file from assets folder if possible.if possible the how to send it.Please provide some code here.thanks.